# How can I improve my reaction speed and timing for martial arts?

Tags: martial-arts, speed

I'm interested in what exercises/training I can do to help with reaction time and timing for martial arts.  Specifically, how can I improve parrying and countering a strike?  I'm not looking for speed drills (speed is different than reaction time and timing).  I need to be able to react based on some cue and then determine the on-coming strike speed so I can appropriately parry it and counter...any suggestions?

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of one or more MA.SE questions: http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/241/drills-for-reducing-your-natural-flinch-reaction and http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/869/how-do-i-improve-my-attack-speed and http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/704/what-exercises-help-to-develop-frontal-leg-speed

Answer (score 4):

Anderson Silva, who is what one could conservatively call one of the most successful counter-punchers in modern mixed martial arts, includes two elements in his training that I would say are vital to that success:

- Copious sparring, focusing on technique and defense
- [Dodging a racquetball thrown at his head](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lwkeNzW8gOg)

Other than footwork drills for **agility**, **conditioning** work to make sure you're fresh enough to present an intelligent defense, drilling **boxing defense and head movement** techniques, and **power training** to develop explosiveness, I would focus on these two methods (mostly the first) for improving one's martial arts reaction time.

Comment: Was disappointed when the link didn't take me [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ZXHsNqkDI4)

Answer (score 2):

Given that you seem to be very experienced in the field, i.e. know all the technical aspects of the situations back and forth, and assuming that you are fit, it might make sense to focus on **meditation**.

Over time, meditation can help you with of seeing the situation as it really is and that might be better for reaction speed and timing than basing the reaction pattern on a specific cue.

I did a search at Google Scholar, see [Google Scholar: meditation and reaction time](http://scholar.google.se/scholar?q=meditation%20and%20reaction%20time&btnG=&hl=sv&as_sdt=0,5) and - for example - [Effect of buddhist meditation on....](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/003193849190543W) seems to support this.

My own experience from playing basketball is that I was more likely to get into a "flow" state (i.e. where your opponents seems to be in slow motion) if I have had the possibility to meditate before the games.

Besides meditating before home games, I did it 15-20 minutes twice a day, just based on reading about it, not following any particular meditation school.

Comment: so you think meditation/visualization works for reaction and timing...have you done any 'physical' types of training in addition to that?

Comment: yes, that was my experience from playing basketball. The physical part of the training that improved timing and reaction was drills where you worked on 1-1 and 3-3 plays, in your context, that probably means actual sparring.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a deep-level answer to your question by studying D.T. Suzuki's book *Zen in Japanese Culture* and he goes even deeper in his essay in *Zen Buddhism and Psychoanalysis* (by Fromm, Suzuki, and De Martino). The picture is filled out by Eugen Herrigel in *Zen in the Art of Archery*. Thinking to ourselves in words gets in the way of responses that have been trained into us by long practice. We need to be able to put the conceptualizing part of our minds into the deep background when a crisis-reaction demand comes up. Zhuang Zi talks about the **fully realized human** with the same needs in mind

Comment: The practical advice I can read from your answer basically states: "Train more and you will get better", am I correct?

Comment: Training the body can train the mind, true. The first time I did basic 5-attack sparring in my dojo I could tell that my awareness was sort of like when you trip over something and really have a spill. But despite having a very large fist end up an in in front of my nose nothing bad happened. The next time I was a little more mindful, and so forth. <p> However, I was ahead of other people at my 8 kyu rank because I knew how to do meditation and I knew how to direct my mind to cease talking to itself in words. Michael Jordan got coaching from psychologists on how to get into the "zone."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's much you can  beyond practicing (Unlime others here I'm skeptical about meditation), but make sure to practice a lot.

- Practice slow, or in a speed that you can execute the technique 100% correctly (so you don't drill wrong movements), and increase speed from there. Make sure your partners understand this also.
- Conditioning - during sparring or other exercises, you don't want to be distracted by beeing exhausted, having aching muscle etc.